# How can I set the build destination in Team Services for WIX

Tags: wix, azure-devops

I am using Windows installer xml and now my project moves to Team Services.

However, my Paths wont work anymore and I need to update my setup.

On the local build machine I used this hardlink: C:\Projects\Solution\Project\bin\Release\Assembly.dll

My Question: What is the best way to build 4 projects and then run a 5th project, which uses the assemblies in the bin/release directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a reference to the project and then use $(var.Project.TargetPath) instead of the hardlink (or $(var.Project.TargetDir)Assembly.dll). The references will add dependencies on those projects to the wixproj which means they all must be build before the wixproj so all the binaries will exist. All the projects should be included in the same solution as the wixproj.

Here's a resource for all the automatically defined compile time variables you can use http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/votive_project_references.html

Alternatively if you can't do it this way you can define the variables in the <DefineConstants> of the wixproj. It would be something like "ProjectDir=$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\Project\bin\Release\" and then in your wix component where you are using the SourceDir hardlink you would use SourceDir=$(var.ProjectDir)Assembly.dll

All of this stuff is taking advantage of MSBuild. It takes a long time to wrap your head around how MSBuild works but it is definitely worth it if you will be using Visual Studio to build all your projects.